# upload entire folder to a specific folder on Azure blob

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I know how to upload entire folder to a contain on Azure blob, it is this:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container $ContainerName -Context $ctx
```

My question is that if I have a folder under my container, saying it is "test". How can I upload all the files/subfloders of my local folder to Azuure blob mycontainer/test/.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To create a folder in container, we just need to use the combination of path and file name as the blob name.

The object returned by Get-ChildItem has a property called FullName. Then we can use substring method to remove the disk letter.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse C:\Test\ | ForEach-Object { Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File $_.FullName -Blob $_.FullName.Substring(3) -Container uploaded -Context $ctx }
```

Here is the screenshot of my lab:

[image: Lab]

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to command line tool [AzCopy](http://aka.ms/azcopy) or its core library [Azure Storage Data Movement Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement/), which supports fast transferring for folders and can be paused & resumed.

Answer (score 1):

Now it is possible to add files into blob storage into the folder. All you need to do is to download [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/). Then you can use it to edit files and folders inside your blob storage:

[image]

Or open the app directly from Azure:

[image]